# Convergence of a sequence w.r.t French Railway Metric

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, solution-verification, metric-spaces

So I'm given the following version of the French Railway Metric:
$$
d^{'}_{f}(z_1, z_2) = 
\begin{cases}
|z_1 - z_2| & \text{if } \exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R} \text{ such that } z_1 = \lambda z_2,\\
|z_1| + |z_2| & \text{otherwise. }
\end{cases}
$$
As a part of this question I have verified that this is a metric and I have described the closed balls $B_1(z)$ of radius $1$ with respect to $d^{'}_{f}$ depending on $z \in \mathbb{C}$ as follows:

$B_1(z) = \{u \in \mathbb{C} : |z-u| \leq 1\} \cup \{u \in \mathbb{C} : |u| \leq 1 - |z|\}$

If $|z| > 1$

$ \implies \{u \in \mathbb{C} : |u| \leq 1 - |z|\} = \emptyset$.

$\implies B_1(z) = \{u \in \mathbb{C} : |z-u| \leq 1\}$

I.e., $B_1(z)$ is the disc centred at $z$ of radius $1$ in the complex plane.

If $|z| \leq 1$

$\implies B_1(z) = \{u \in \mathbb{C} : |z-u| \leq 1\} \cup \{u \in \mathbb{C} : |u| \leq 1 - |z|\}$.

I.e., $B_1(z)$ is the union of all discs centred at the origin of radius $r \leq 1 - |z|$ with the disc centred at $z$ of radius $1$, in the complex plane.

(Hopefully that's okay...)

**The question then asks:** check whether or not the sequence $\left(1 + \frac{i}{n} \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges with respect to $d^{'}_{f}$ and justify your answer.

So, I'm fairly sure this series converges to 1 w.r.t $d^{'}_{f}$, I'm just really struggling to show this formally -- I've always struggled with the whole epsilon limit stuff!! And, I'm completely new to metric spaces. **Here is an attempt:**

For simplicity let $\left(1 + \frac{i}{n} \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} = \left(x_n\right)_n$ and let $x \in \mathbb{C}$.

The union of open balls $U_r(x)$ is a set containing every open neighborhood of $x$ (?) as it is open and any neighborhood of $x$ must be a subset of $U_r(x)$ for some $r>0$.

A lemma in my course notes states: $x_n \rightarrow x$ w.r.t $d^{'}_{f}$ iff for every open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n \in U$ for all $n \geq N$.

I claim that $x_n \rightarrow 1$ w.r.t $d^{'}_{f}$ (and here comes my interpretation)

$\implies \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$  such that  $x_n \in U_{\epsilon}(1) \iff |1 - x_n| < \epsilon$, $\forall n \geq N$

$\iff |1-1-(i/n)|< \epsilon$, $\forall n \geq N$

$\iff N > 1/\epsilon $

And, clearly for any $\epsilon > 0$ we can always find such an $N \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus, the sequence $\left(1 + \frac{i}{n} \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges with respect to $d^{'}_{f}$.

How is this? Is my working correct?

Comment: Your definition of the closed balls doesn't quite work. The first term as written is the entire radius 1 disk around z but it needs the additional restriction that $u=\lambda z$ for $\lambda$ real.

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong, but I think your analysis is not correct.

In fact for $\vert z\vert\geq \delta>0$, I think $B_\epsilon(z)=\{\lambda z: \lambda\in \mathbb{R}, \vert \lambda-1\vert< \frac{\epsilon}{\vert z\vert} \}$ for any $\epsilon<\delta$.

In the sequence you look at, $z_n:=1+\frac{i}{n}$ are all linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$. This means that $d_f'(z_n,z_m)= \vert 1+\frac{i}{n}\vert +\vert 1+\frac{i}{m}\vert \geq 2$, and the sequence is not even Cauchy.

---

**Later edit:**

Maybe I should clarify some things. I think the balls in this case are the union of two disjoint sets.

$$ B_r^{(1)}(z):= \{\lambda z: \lambda\in \mathbb{R}, \vert z-\lambda z\vert< r \} \quad \text{and} \quad B_r^{(2)}(z):=\{ z': |z' |< r - |z| \}\setminus \{ \lambda z:  \lambda\in \mathbb{R} \} $$

$B_r^{(2)}(z)$ is simply empty when $r\leq \vert z\vert$. When $z=0$, $B_r^{(1)}(z)=\{0\}$ and $B_r^{(2)}(z)= \{ z': \vert z'\vert<r \}\setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: Yes, I understand more now. I think I will post a tentative answer soon. But, what if $z=0$ (for the description of the closed ball)? Would it just be $0$?

Comment: Or would it be $\{0\} \cup \{ u \in \mathbb{C} : u \neq \lambda z, \text{ for any } \lambda \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and } |u| \leq 1\}$ (although this second set doesn't exist (?) because we could have $\lambda = 0$)? Or does there just not exist a closed ball of radius 1 centered at $z$...?

Comment: @spooleey For $z=0$, the balls are the standard balls. Plugging $z_2=0$ in the definition by cases, gives you that the distance of $z_1$ to $z_2=0$ is just $\vert z_1\vert$. Or maybe I misunderstood what you are asking.

Comment: Would the second part of the metric not exist for $z_1 = 0$ though? As $\lambda$ could just be $0$ and so any complex number would fall into the first case. In which case $B_1 (z_1) = \{\lambda z_1 \in \mathbb{C} : |z_1-\lambda z_1 | \leq 1\} = \{0\}$?

Comment: @spooleey Actually, I was wrong. If $z_2=0$ there are no $z_1\neq 0$ such that $z_1=\lambda z_2$. The open balls around $0$ are still the standard Euclidean balls, though.